# bxSlider images drop left

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

Couldn't find better title,
let me explain you what is the issue.

In the bxSlider I tried to load images from the host itself (images from an images folder) once I load the page I can see that the images loaded vertically to the left.

http://gyazo.com/c0855e4bceb8f2e24bdeb1d4c61cacaf.png

the images stays there until the bxslider is fully loaded. then the images appears in the bxslider like it should be.

I tried the bxSlider's example when they used the placehold.it site to use an image.

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar1">
```

With this line the bxSlider working as it should be.
the slider display the spinner and then the photos.

So what's wrong here .. ? why external images displaying the spinner.gif and the images from the host itself not ?

Code:

```
<div id="slider">
    <div><img src="image.png"></div>
    <div><img src="image.png"></div>
    <div><img src="image.png"></div>
    <div><img src="image.png"></div>
    <div><img src="image.png"></div>
    <div><img src="image.png"></div>
    <div><img src="image.png"></div>
    <div><img src="image.png"></div>
</div>

p_slider = $('#slider').bxSlider({
            slideWidth: 254,
            minSlides: 2,
            maxSlides: 4,
            slideMargin: 5,
            pager: 0
        }).hide().fadeIn();
```

Comment: Are you working on a "live" website/localhost or out of a folder on your computer?
And can you post some of the relevant HTML/JS code?

Comment: Sure, I can post .. :) and I tried it's the same problem on the localhost (wamp) and website (nginx) I'll edit the question and add some code.